# Debug JavaScript with VS 2012

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2012

I was using VS 2010 for a long time and actually was able to place break points in the javascript of a page and debug the code.  Now, with VS 2012, I can no longer do that.  Does anyone know why or if there is a way to debug?

Answer (score 1):

did you check what's the default browser used when running application from VS2012? Note that you can only debug JavaScript file using IE

Comment: that was indeed the problem.  Thanks!

Comment: that's great. If you think I answered your concern maybe can you accept the answer :)

Comment: Jobert, Thanks for the answer.  I had been using Chrome and wondering why I could not set breakpoints in the code.  I like the Chrome development tools, but sometimes I want to set breakpoints from VS in the javascript.